# Android display progress dialog in front of alert dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog

I have a problem with my progress dialog from AsyncTask. Here's the scenario. I have an app which has an alert dialog, then checks something from db. If result is true then will call an AsyncTask which displays a progress dialog. Progress dialog is displaying behind Alert dialog. How can I display progress dialog in front of alert dialog?

AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadBibleActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.translating_bible_version));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

Alert Dialog:

```
private void displayDialog() {
    customDialog = new Dialog(this);
    customDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.share));
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    etTitle = (EditText) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etDescription = (EditText) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.etDescription);

    if(caller == 1) {

        String userVersion = dbHelper.getUserVersion(userId);

        if((userVersion != null && !userVersion.isEmpty())
                && !userVersion.equalsIgnoreCase("TLC")) {

            if(ConnectionDetector.hasNetworkConnection(this)) {
                scrapeTask = new ScrapeAsyncTask();
                scrapeTask.execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            etTitle.setKeyListener(null);
            etTitle.setText(verse);
            etDescription.setText("\"" + text + "\"");
            etDescription.requestFocus();
        }

    } else {
        etTitle.setHint(text);
        etTitle.requestFocus();
        etDescription.setHint(text);
    }

    customDialog.show();
}
```

Any ideas? Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show me some screen shot

Answer (score 0):

try calling `customDialog.show();`

before `scrapeTask = new ScrapeAsyncTask();`